# Post request is not successfull in angular js project?

Tags: angularjs

```
**Here is my app.js**
 var app = angular.module("app", []);
    app.controller("HttpGetController", function ($scope, $http) {

        $scope.SendData = function () {
           // use $.param jQuery function to serialize data from JSON 
            var data = $.param({
                fName: $scope.firstName,
                lName: $scope.lastName
            });

            var config = {
                headers : {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'
                }
            }

            $http.post('/PostRequest/RequestForm.html', data, config)
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.PostDataResponse = data;
            })
            .error(function (data, status, header, config) {
                $scope.ResponseDetails = "Data: " + data +
                    "<hr />status: " + status +
                    "<hr />headers: " + header +
                    "<hr />config: " + config;
            });
        };

    });

**here is my html**
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src = "js/app.js"></script>
<script src = "js/jquery.js"></script>
<body>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="HttpGetController">
    <p>First Name: <input type="text" name="firstName" ng-model="firstName" required /></p>
    <p>First Name: <input type="text" name="lastName" ng-model="lastName" required /></p>
    <button ng-click="SendData()">Submit</button>
    <hr />
    {{ PostDataResponse }}
    {{ ResponseDetails }}
</div>
</body>
```

---

I have created a dynamicwebproject in eclipse .But when I run this program I am getting following output[image]
**I don't know whether I have passed the right url in post request.I getting the Requestfrom.html as output.Please let me now how to resolve this problem and how to pass the url which is right.**

Comment: is it your server path  '/PostRequest/RequestForm.html'?

Comment: wheres your doctype and html tags? whats happening in your browsers net tab? is the post being made?

Comment: Sorry for being late.

Comment: I don't know the server path .I have made the path that u have said just by assuming.Please let me know How to find out server path